# How to debug on local jboss as 7 using Eclipse 3.7

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jboss7.x

I am using Eclipse 3.7 and I added JBoss as 7.1 server.
I want to know how to debug a Java EE application deployed on this local server using Eclipse?

What is the needed debug configuration that I should use?
Note that I am using JBoss Tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way!
its pretty simple, just install Eclipse indigo 3.7.2 
and install jboss web tools 3.3 beta1 (the current newest release)
and add jboss application server 7.1.1 Final.
and right click your application (in eclipse) --> debug as --> server --> choose jboss as 7.1.1 and it will run smoothly in debug mode.

Note: I was unable to debug my application as I used older version for jboss tools.